# I am given the following numerical controlling system:

Tags: matlab

[image]

To create a MATLAB program that simulates the operation of the system at the step input (the graphs of `v(t)`, `e(t)`, `u(t)`, and `y(t)` are required).
I did not find any example, I do not know where to start and how to approach this requirement Some clues, please.

Comment: You could derive the closed-loop gain that is equivalent to the loop and then uses the `tf()` function to construct your closed-loop transfer function/gain. Then find the step response by input the result of `tf()` into the `step()` function. [MATLAB documentation: Step response plot of dynamic system; step response data](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/lti.step.html).

Comment: If you want all the graph of the other parts you might have to derive the closed loop gain relative to where you're taking the output. A way of verifying is using MATLAB's Simulink to check if you get the same results.

Answer (score 1):

### Plotting Step Response for a Random System/Transfer Function

Here is a step response plot of a random system, where the period of the step is `0.5` seconds which is configured by the variable `Step_End` inputted into the `step()` function. I'll leave the computation of the respective transfer functions up to you. To find the closed-loop gain of a system you can employ the general form:

[image: Closed-Loop Gain]

Where `G_inner` is the gain along the path that is not a part of the loop. Furthermore when there is a gain along the feedback path you can adapt the equation's denominator as `1 + H_Process*G_inner` where `H_Process` the gain along the feedback.

[image: Transfer Function Step Response]

```
%Random numerator coefficients%
a = 4;

%Random denominator coefficients%
b = 1;
c = 2;
d = 10;

%Creating the transfer function%
Numerator = [a];
Denominator = [b c d];
Transfer_Function = tf(Numerator, Denominator);
Transfer_Function

%Checking the step response with period 0.5%
Step_End = 0.5;
step(Transfer_Function,Step_End);
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**